# DB consuming large space

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

i am newbie to mongoDB ,as i start working with test application (ASP.Net)  found that the db consuming large disk space.I was wondering that collections have only small piece of data like a word.So does anybody can shed some light on this ?

Please correct me if am wrong.Thanks in advance

Comment: how you check its consuming large space? what are the stats?

Comment: Well basically MongoDb consumes much disk space you could also read more from here http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Excessive+Disk+Space

Comment: when i checked across data/db ,files size about to 16MB.

Comment: when i checked across data/db ,files size about to 16MB. fileSize and nsSizeMB are 1677216 ,16 respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo doesn't shrink previously allocated structures because that would slow database down. When you need it, run the [repair procedure](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair) to rebuild DB and reclaim unused space. On live project you should schedule it to off-peak hours.

From the command line:

```
mongod --repair
```

From the shell (you have to do for all dbs including local if you go this route):

```
db.repairDatabase();
```

Comment: yes this works well > db.keyword.dataSize()
23358548
> db.keyword.totalSize()
33423184
> db.repairDatabase()
{ "ok" : 1 }
> db.keyword.totalSize()
21307280
> db.keyword.dataSize()
13821140

Comment: This is essentially correct - I would point out though, that MongoDB does reuse the space when appropriate.  Also: an alternative to running a repair, if you are using replica sets (which you should be), is to just do a full resync of a secondary - no need to take anything offline, and it has the same effect on the data.